# Sql server 2014 counted columns into another table

Tags: sql-server

hello everyone I am new to programming and I would like some help on this issue I am facing.

I have two tables `clients` and `box`.

```
clients (id,name....boxnum)

box(id,totalbox,usedbox,availablebox)
```

what I am trying to do is get the available box in the `box` table according to a rule that (`availablebox`=`total`-`used`) where `used` is counted in the clients table

example:

```
----------
client    box
----------
a         1
----------
b         2
----------
c         1
----------
```

what I need is to count each time the box num repeated in clients table and get the value of it to use it in the box table as usedbox.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: used this: Select COUNT (BoxNum) As BoxUsed
From Clients
group by BoxNum   how can i insert the counted value into the other tabel , please

Answer (score 1):

Use `Count` Aggregate and `Group By` clause

```
Select Box,count(*) as Box_Count
From Yourtable 
Group by Box
```

If you want to insert the `count` result into another table then use `Insert into..select` syntax

```
Insert into Target_table(Box,Box_Count)
Select Box,count(*) as Box_Count
From Yourtable 
Group by Box
```